# HttpClient is not found in .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, httpclient, .net-4.5

I am trying to use the new `HttpClient` in .NET 4.5, but Visual Studio complains that it doesn't exist. I have `System.Net`, but when I type `System.Net.Http`, it complains for that too.

Am I supposed to download a new distributable for this class?

Comment: You need to reference the `System.Net.Http` assembly. Also, PCLs don't support using that class, so you're out of luck if that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks but I don't have it listed in the Add Assemblies dialog.

Comment: What type of project are you developing?

Comment: PCL? This is a windows forms app.

Comment: Not sure what else might be going on, other than ensuring that the "Targeting" option in the Reference Manager window is set to the 4.5 framework.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Add a reference to `System.Net.Http`:

[image: add ref]

Comment: Thanks but I don't have it listed in the Add Assemblies dialog.

Comment: CS project .NET target version?

Comment: Thanks, something is wrong. I tried it now, and it shows up, but when I try to add, it assembly doesn't get added. Anyway I think this is a VS related issue.

Comment: That wasn't enough for me, you also need to add a reference to System.Net.Http.WebRequest

Answer (score 24):

I had the same problem. After some digging around, i found you had to install [this package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http) and then add the reference to `System.Net.Http` for it to not complain!

Comment: This solved it for me.
I have a xamarin solution which has a PCL, a WindowsPhone app, an Android and an iPhone app. I wanted to use HttpClient in the PCL, but if I just added the reference to System.Net.Http, my project would get re-targeted and become incompatible with my windows phone app.
Installing this package prevented my PCL for getting re-targeted and now everything compiles just fine :)

Comment: That wasn't enough for me, I also had to add System.Net.Http.WebRequest

Comment: This worked for me on an ASP.NET 4.5.1 project. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Start using vs2017, and encounter same problem, when creating Native + PCL, couldn't find the HttpClient, going to Nuget and get Microsoft.Net.Http solve my problems.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the issue when I added a class inside the `App_Code` folder having this `HttpClient` called in one of my function. Upon spending countless hours I found that the **`Build Action`** under `Properties` for my class is set to **`Content`**.

Changing this **`Build Action`** to **`Compile`** fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I simply:

1. Closed Visual Studio
2. Re-opened it

Boom. It found HttpClient.