# System.Net.Http is missing

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am trying to download mp3 files using `HTTPClient` in `System.Net.Http` namespace, but it looks vs 2012 doesn't recognize it. I created project under .Net 4.5 and it's not recognized.

I am looking to use `HttpClient`, I see some posts stating that add this from `NuGet`, but I don't how to find that in `NuGet`? or at least add a reference to this?

Answer (score 10):

Just click on

Tools>Library Package Manager>Package Manager console

Then you will see a command prompt under source edit area.

then type Following Command

**ex: PM> Install-Package System.Net.Http -Version 2.0.20710**

Hope this will be helpful ( This is for VS2010, Hopefully this would be same to VS2012 as well )

Comment: this is error I get while executing the command. Install-Package : Could not install package 'Microsoft.Net.Http 2.0.20710.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'WindowsPhone,Version=v8.0', but the package does not contain any 
assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Comment: Try
Project>Manage Nuget Packages> Online 
then in the search box type "NETFx HttpEntityClient"
and install

Comment: getting same error while installation, I think this assembly is not for windows phone 8.

Comment: Works fine for VS2010, just tested it and confirmed this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference the correct assembly (`System.Net.Http`)

See [HttpClient is not found in .NET 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16326522/httpclient-is-not-found-in-net-4-5) for more details.

Answer (score -1):

You can use WebClient to download Mp3 file . [Here](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Asynchronous_Programming_For_Windows_Phone_8) is more description about webclient

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have not yet checked it, Can i show progress with it?

Comment: WebClient has Downloadprogresschanged event where you can find how much byte you received

Comment: This is deprecated.

Answer (score -1):

It is just in GAC. Simply add the System.Net.Http reference in the framework category.

Comment: in GAC (C:\Windows\assembly) I only see System.Net, there is System.Net.Http. I am coding for windows phone8