# System.Net.Http missing?

Tags: asp.net, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to run Test.aspx:

```
<%@ Page language="c#" EnableViewState="true" ContentType="text/html" Async="true" %>

<script language="C#" runat="server">

    void Page_Load(Object Src, EventArgs E )
    {
        RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(BindData));
    }

    private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task BindData()
    {
        Response.Write("Hello?<br /><br />");

        using (System.Net.Http.HttpClient httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
        {
            Response.Write(await httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://www.google.com"));
        }

        Response.Write("<br /><br />Is this thing on?<br /><br />");
    }

</script>
```

and getting this error:

```
Test.aspx(14): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Http' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Net' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

The System.Net.Http.dll assembly is in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4\Assemblies
```

and in IIS Manager the Basic Settings' Application Pool is ASP.NET v4.0 (Integrated).  Has anyone run into this?

UPDATE: I installed .Net 4.5.2 and added the following web.config

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
   <compilation>
      <assemblies>
         <add assembly="System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
      </assemblies>
   </compilation>
  </system.web>

</configuration>
```

and it worked.

Comment: make sure you are referencing System.Net.Http.dll in .NET 4.5

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16326522/httpclient-is-not-found-in-net-4-5

Comment: This is a standalone .aspx page without a code-behind. It is not part of a solution or project and is not in Visual Studio.  Adding <%@ Import Namespace="System.Net.Http" %> does not help.

Comment: 1) Nothing will help if you don't have the proper framework version. *Do* you have 4.5 installed? 2) [Import](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb44kack(v=vs.100).aspx)  is for namespaces. You need to use [Assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/d864zc1k(v=vs.100).aspx) to add a reference to a dll. You need a reference to the assembly no matter what IDE you are using. VS just makes it easier to add them

Comment: 4.5 is installed and adding an Assembly reference raises an error about targeting the runtime. I am pretty sure 4.5 was installed before, since it comes with Windows Server 2012 R2.

Comment: To resolve this I had to add <add assembly="System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/> and <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" /> to the web.config

Comment: @MarkF You should post that as an answer and then accept it, instead of editing the question.

Comment: I have this <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"> and it still works.

Answer (score 11):

To resolve this I had to add

```
<add assembly="System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
```

and

```
 <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
```

to the web.config

Answer (score 1):

I've tried this highly suggested solution (I found this as accepted answer in many similar questions here in SO)

on `Web.Config` write this and rebuild the solution

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
       <add assembly="System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
</system.web>
```

But unfortunately, I've no luck with this. At last, I've found a solution which works for me and saved my day :)

1. Right-click the `References` folder > `Add Reference...`
2. Expand Assemblies on the left side of the window and select Framework.
3. Scroll to and select `System.Net.Http` in the list of assemblies.
   Make sure the box next to `System.Net.Http` is checked, then click
   `OK`.
4. Rebuild the project.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the issue started occurring after upgrading to .NET Framework 4.7.2. I found out that Nuget package for System.Net.Http is no longer recommended. Here are workarounds:

- [Single-name references are removed by the SDK](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/blob/master/releases/net472/KnownIssues/613745%20-%20Single-name%20references%20are%20removed%20by%20the%20SDK%20when%20targeting%204.7.2.md)
- [Nuget package for System.Net.Http on .NET Framework 4.7.2 and newer versions](https://port135.com/2020/08/01/nuget-package-system-net-http-framework/)

Answer (score -1):

To resolve my problem, Just add this in webconfig.

```
<add assembly="System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
```

and

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
```