# Why does System.Net.Http not get packaged?

Tags: c#

I have an application that has a NuGet reference to `System.Net.Http` (among, obviously, many other references).

When I build a package of this application using "Publish", and selecting the "from CD" option, it compiles the installation into a local folder, with all the binaries packed into `.deploy` files.  All, that is, except `System.Net.Http.dll`.

I have tried many different workarounds, changing the properties of the `System.Net.Http` reference in the project, then removing the NuGet reference and adding it instead as an Assembly reference from the .NET Framework.  Nothing doing.  This particular DLL seems to be uniquely resistant to being packaged along with the rest of the binaries.

If it makes any difference, I'm working with .NET Framework 4.6.2.

Why is this behavior happening?  How to fix it?

**UPDATE:**
Based on the comments below I investigated Project Properties > Publish > Application Files.  `System.Net.Http.dll` was not listed among the options.  So I hacked it by changing the "Publish Status" of `System.Net.Http.Extensions.dll` to "Include" (instead of "Include (Auto)"), which added a section to my project file, which I then edited to remove the ".Extensions", thus:

```
<ItemGroup>
<PublishFile Include="System.Net.Http">
  <Visible>False</Visible>
  <Group>
  </Group>
  <TargetPath>
  </TargetPath>
  <PublishState>Include</PublishState>
  <IncludeHash>True</IncludeHash>
  <FileType>Assembly</FileType>
</PublishFile>
</ItemGroup>
```

Now my project application files list contains `System.Net.Http`... sort of:

[image]

Well, clearly something is very confused here.  `System.Net.Http` is simultaneously referenced and not referenced.  And when I publish, even though I have explicitly included it, `System.Net.Http.dll` is *still* not published.

Comment: do you include it in your publish?

Comment: @ShahroozAnsari What do you mean?  Where is there an option to include (or exclude) any particular file in the publishing process?

Comment: Check if it's included in project properties > Publish > Application Files

Comment: in properties of your project is publish and at there is a button (application Files) at there you choose with files be include or exclude

Comment: @ShahroozAnsari Well here's the crazy thing.  I opened that dialog, and `System.Net.Http.dll` does not even appear in the list!  What's up with that?!

Comment: go to your refrence add this dll and on properties of that dll set copy to lochal

Comment: i suggest to you set your framework on 4.5 and set in your prerequard option this

Comment: @ShahroozAnsari It is already set "Copy Local=true".  The DLL appears in the `bin\debug` folder after compiling.  But it still doesn't appear in the "Application Files"

Comment: are you sure the file is not at  properties > Publish > Application Files ???

Comment: @ShahroozAnsari Yes.  100% certain.  It jumps from `System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll` to `System.Net.Http.Extensions.dll`

Comment: change your freamwork to 4.5  i think it will be run corectly  whatch this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16326522/httpclient-is-not-found-in-net-4-5

Comment: @Evk see my update please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143246/discussion-between-shaul-behr-and-shahrooz-ansari).

Comment: Spot on, @Evk, the duplicated question has the right answer for me!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in project properties of your project is publish and at there is a button (application Files) at there you choose with files be include or exclude 
go there and include dlls need project
if it not work
add dll like exist file and make it copy always it will work